# Long PathClass (input line too large)

Tags: scala, sbt, classpath

I'm trying to execute a `.bat` file using CMD on windows. the command: `D:\Candidate_Retrieval\target\universal\candidate-retrieval-1.0\bin> candidate-retrieval`

The error was:

> The input line is too long.
>
> The syntax of the command is incorrect.

I opened the .bat file and I found the classpath as follows:

```
 set "APP_CLASSPATH=%APP_LIB_DIR%\..\conf\;
%APP_LIB_DIR%\candidate-retrieval.candidate-retrieval-1.0-sans-externalized.jar;%APP_LIB_DIR%\org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.11.7.jar;%APP_LIB_DIR%\com.typesafe.play.twirl-api_2.11-1.1.1.jar;%APP_LIB_DIR%\org.apache.commons.commons-lang3-3.4.jar;%APP_LIB_DIR%\org.scala-lang.modules.scala-xml_2.11-1.0.1.jar;%APP_LIB_DIR%\com.typesafe.play.play-server_2.11-2.4.8.jar;%APP_LIB_DIR%\com.typesafe.play.play_2.11-2.4.8.jar;%APP_LIB_DIR%\com.typesafe.play.build-link-2.4.8.jar;%APP_LIB_DIR%\com.typesafe.play.play-exceptions-2.4.8.jar;%APP_LIB_DIR%\org.javassist.javassist-3.19.0-GA.jar;%APP_LIB_DIR%\com.typesafe.play.play-iteratees_2.11-2.4.8.jar;%APP_LIB_DIR%\org.scala-stm.scala-stm_2.11-0.7.jar;%APP_LIB_DIR%\com.typesafe.config-1.3.0.jar; ... .jars
```

I made some search, the solutions could be one of these: https://www.scala-sbt.org/sbt-native-packager/recipes/longclasspath.html.

but I don't know how to apply them. could someone elaborate more in simple steps?

Can `longpathtool` helps? how?

Comment: Whoever voted to close as off-topic: I can't think of anyone *except* programmers who use SBT, so it's definitely a tool "primarily used by programmers".

Comment: please add more details to your question so we can help. show us the full .bat file and the full error